# How to implement multiselect in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to mimic the spreadsheet feature where I can select multiple table cells by pressing `shift` + `mouseover`, and I am having some trouble getting it to select the nearby cells that fall within the start and end range of the selection. So for example, with a 3x3 grid, cell `0,0` is the start cell, when I mouseover `0,1`, and `1,1` `1,0` should also get selected as it falls within the range. Here is the logic I have so far, but it only selects the cells as the mouse passes over (non of the adjacent cells get selected).

Here is my code:

```
 selectCell (row, col) {
  this.coors.push({x: row, y: col})
  let len = this.coors.length - 1
  this.start = {x: this.coors[0].x, y: this.coors[0].y}
  this.end = {x: this.coors[len].x, y: this.coors[len].y}
  this.grid[row].splice(col, 1, 2)
  this.iterateOverGrid(2)
},
iterateOverGrid (col) {
  for (let i = this.start.x; i <= this.end.x; i++) {
    this.grid[i].splice(this.end.y, 1, col)
    for (let j = this.start.y; j <= this.end.y; j++) {
      this.grid[i].splice(this.end.y, 1, col)
    }
  }
},
```

`start` holds the x and y position of the first cell selected; `end` holds the x and y position of the last cell selected. The idea is to iterate over each row and column in the grid (which I am attempting to do in my `iterateOverGrid()` method) and then assign a value of `2` to each cell that falls within the `start` `end` parameter. How exactly can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to create a multiselect as a vue component? which vue.js do you use? Do you know about [vue-multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) ?

Comment: @LakiGeri I am using Vue.js 2.0. I am aware of vue-multiselect, but it seems that is for dropdown menus. Whereas what I am after is multiselecting cells in a table.